# Error 401 while using Selenium and Python to log into zoom on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, selenium, raspberry-pi, zoom-sdk

I am learning to use Selenium and my goal is to open zoom through a python program on a Raspberry Pi 4. Upon running the pasted code, the program works as intended; opens zoom in browser, maximizes window, selects and clicks sign in, enters credentials and then presses enter. After log in is attempted I am given "error: Http 401 error". I am guessing this is because zoom is detecting an auto-login and blocking me. First off, am I correct? And if so, is there any way to get around this? Or does zoom block any auto filling of credentials.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver=webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://zoom.us")
driver.maximize_window()

elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'SIGN IN')]").click()
emailField = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='email']")
emailField.send_keys("email")          #"email" replaced with zoom login
passField = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='password']")
passField.send_keys("password")        #"password" replaced with zoom password 
passField.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: you can be right. I used Selenium to open Firefox and later I try manually login, reset password, create new account - and all of them give `error: Http 401 error`. But if I open Firefox manually then all work correctly.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do after login but zoom has [API](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api) so maybe you can do it with `requests` and `API`

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you find any solution so far to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and was able to get around the bot-detection by using
the [undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues) package.

replace

```
from selenium import webdriver
...
driver = webdriver.chrome()
```

with

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as ucdriver
...
driver = ucdriver.Chrome()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code, right after the libraries import, and it will work:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
#in executable_path put the path to your chromedriver.exe
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://zoom.us")
```